# Google Sign in - In app browser vs mobile browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser, google-signin

My app uses google sign in. I m getting the error as
"Error: disallwed_useragent" with the following code.
Please find the error screenshot.

```
GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.uiDelegate = self;
signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
signIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;
signIn.allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,nil];
[signIn signIn];
```

So I updated the code as

```
signIn.allowsSignInWithWebView = NO;
signIn.allowsSignInWithBrowser = YES;
```

The error was gone. When trying the sign in with google, it goes to mobile safari and works fine.

But I doubt whether it will be rejected by app store with the below reason.

"We found the following issues with the user interface of your app:

The app opens a web page in mobile Safari for logging into Google+, then returns the user to the app. The user should be able to log in without opening Safari first."

So Anyone suggest me the best way for google sign in. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your googlesignin key is not configure make it configure first and then use it

Comment: GoogleService-Info.plist check your this file in your project

Comment: In my plist, I have my ID com.googleusercontent.apps.131.. Its working when I give allowsSignInWithWebView to NO and allowsSignInWithBrowser to YES.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Google has updated its security restrictions for OAuth flow. They are not going to allow native web-views to initiate OAuth flows, but rather are encouraging people to use the OS browsers to do so. In your case, you'll probably have to wait for the Google calendar SDK to update their code to obey the newly recommended flow. More information is available in the [Google blog](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

Comment: And apple won't reject the app if I use OS browser before I get update with Google calendar SDK?